# Wifi interface recognized as ethernet

Tags: arch-linux, networkmanager, network-interface, netctl

I am having trouble setting up my wifi configuration persistently.

I have tried both netctl and NetworkManager and both only work after manual setup.

What I find especially weird is that `ip link show` prints

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN     mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc     fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9c:5c:8e:d4:d6:fe brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp0s20f0u13: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 38:2c:4a:47:93:11 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

So interface `enp0s20f0u13` is UP and used for my current connection, which is going through a Wifi dongle. It is recognized as an Ethernet connection but it shouldn't be.

How I get a connection right now is:
after boot I can start `systemctl start netctl@<profile>` and I have a connection. If I start `systemctl start NetworkManager` instead then the service starts not complaining about anything but there is no connection and the Gnome applet doesn't show. Settings -> Network shows no info about any Wifi stuff. If I first start netctl, then stop it, then start NetworkManager *then* Wifi works through NetworkManager, the applet shows and the settings screen shows a Wifi menu.

After having tried lots of stuff I can only hope that the problems arise from this wrong recognition. Any ideas on what to do now?

Comment: Have you tried manually setting up a connection using ``wpa_supplicant`` and ``ip``? If not, that would be my next step in troubleshooting. Sounds like ``netctl`` is setting up ``wpa_supplicant``, so that NM can then correctly handle it.

Comment: NetworkManager should detect your Wi-Fi as such. Sounds like a bug. What is your hardware?

Comment: `wpa_supplicant` complained it couldn't init the driver interface or some such. The driver is working perfectly however. `netctl enable <profile>` successfully auto-connects on boot now. Unless someone points me in the right direction as to actually find out what goes wrong where, I am happy I have Internet on boot right now even though it is not through NetworkManager as I would have preferred, but through netctl.

Comment: Could be fixed by https://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/commit/?id=dd4d8b24da29abfc786ce0b3030c74559b93d034

Impossible to say for sure with the given information.